# An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have one table(Sql server 2014) with 60 million data. while fetching the data i am getting

> "An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

Can any one please help here?

Comment: Can you show us the code that throws this error ?

Comment: select * from tablename

Comment: You never, ever want to do SELECT * FROM tablename .. do you have a WHERE clause on that?  You are essentially pulling down the entire table.

Comment: Try searching for this `ssms out of memory exceptions`

Comment: yes i am using where clause but i have to fetch number of count of ID column.

Comment: You should show your query

Comment: Are you planning to fetch 60 million rows to the screen and then scroll to the end?

Comment: This happens to me (even with small queries) since I often leave Management Studio open for days. I solve it by reopening the program or switching to "Results to text" (instead of grid)

Comment: @MukundM select count(Id) FROM tablename

Answer (score 22):

Close and re-open SQL Management Studio and see if that takes care of it.  Mine does this from time to time even on small queries if I leave it open for too long or have too many query windows open.

Comment: I had 12 query windows opened remotely, I RDP the server directly and it worked for me. re-opening SSMS was the solution.

Comment: I had a similar issue instead of using select *  from the table. Selecting some columns helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SQL Management Studio memory leaking for long running sessions. Restart of it helps to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

If you have opened so many new query editors in the SSMS, that can also cause this error. Try closing unnecessary tabs in SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 : Close and re-opening SQL Server Management Studio and try querying.

Solution 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This exception is caused by SSMS process which  is occupied by long running queries.Don't worry about it , you can try next time and run your query on next tab.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was having problems even with tables with 8 rows.
This worked for me:

- Deleting Temp file present on %temp% location. If the problem still happens restart SSMS.

This happened due to unused temp files.